# TFS 2013 build server prerequisite

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, build-server

I have brand new TFS 2013 build server and the build is currently failing with this error (The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.).

I guess I do not have some software installed on it. One suggestion by Microsoft is to make sure we should have Visual studio installed on the build server.

I just want to know if there is an alternate of installing visual studio on the build server?

Answer (score 1):

I always install Visual Studio on the build servers.  That resolves most of these types of errors.

Comment: Indeed, whist you can isolate and install individual MSbuild targets and tasks, if MS modify them as part of a Service pack / new version of Visual Studio. The updates will get missed on the build server which can lead to confusing build errors as the developers are using different versions of the software to the build server.